# Fast way to compute/estimate ppf of lognorm in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a data intensive application where one of the core computations uses the percent point function of a lognormal distribution.

The code currently uses Scipy, but it is excruciatingly slow. Is there a way to compute/approximate this function using numpy or other package more efficiently?

Comment: You'd highly increase your chances of getting helpful replies if you'd add some code with your current approach, together with some typical parameters for the lognorm and the expected output for some inputs.   How many digits of accuracy are you looking for? Do you need different lognorm parameters for each call? How many calls are you talking about? Did you consider creating a lookup table? ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that you're calling `lognorm.ppf` many times with different values rather than once with all the values in an array? That would slow it down a lot. When I tested it with 10^6 values it took ~81ms. I was able to cut that in half using spline interpolation with an average absolute error of 2e-06, and a maximal absolute error of 0.0023. See code below but that seems not worth to me.

```
from scipy.stats import lognorm
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

s = 1.5
t = np.linspace(0,0.95,10**3)
vals = lognorm.ppf(t, s)
ppf = UnivariateSpline(t,vals,s=10e-10)
x = np.linspace(0,0.95,10**6)
error = np.abs(ppf(x)-lognorm.ppf(x, s))
%timeit ppf(x)
%timeit lognorm.ppf(x, s)
np.mean(error), np.max(error)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what was happening. I had not realized that the function was vectorized, and that the code was calling the function every time within the respective loop.